# Count the number of days between today & the hiredate in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date-arithmetic

How can I count the number of days between (sysdate) & a column called `hiredate` in PL/SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) - TRUNC(t.hiredate) FROM myTable t;
```

This will result in a count of days represented in decimal.  The `TRUNC` of the timestamps will ensure that you will get a consistent result on successive calls.

Answer (score 5):

```
select round((months_between(sysdate,hiredate) * 30),0) from table
```